# Android O : Unable to deactivated snoozed notification

Tags: notifications, android-beta-program

In Android O (Beta OPP4.170623.014), I snoozed an application for one hour for testing purposes.

I have been searching through the System Settings and online as well, and found no way to undo the snooze for the specific notification.

Is it just not supported in the latest beta version of Android O? I do most certainly hope that un-snoozing will be a possibility going forward.

Comment: I don't have  device running O  but [this](http://www.androidauthority.com/android-8-0-review-758783/) says there is a drop down to do that

Comment: In which section do you see that, @beeshyams? I know that it is possible to [undo the action briefly after snoozing](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/03/21/android-o-feature-spotlight-can-snooze-individual-notifications-15m-30m-1hr/).

Comment: If you tap the clock you’ll automatically snooze for 15 minutes but you can open the drop-down menu to snooze for 30 or 60 minutes instead or to **disable snooze**

Comment: Key word: beta.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths I am well aware of that, hence my last sentence in my question

Comment: Any update on this? There's an Android P now...